# Azure ip address refused for docker

Tags: azure, docker, ip-address

I was following the process mention [on the azure site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-docker-machine/) to create a docker machine in azure.

The docker was able to create the necessary components in Azure but comes back with the message of

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Building the docker image or simply trying to query it with `docker images` returns this message.

I suspect that the IP Address assigned is not made public although it is configured in Azure. [image] [image].

This is probably not docker related but to the Azure configuration. How does one ensure the IPAddress here is accessible and connectable externally?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your docker machine provisionned in Azure can't be accessed with your local docker client.
As shown, your IP adress is indeed Public, but the Azure machine may be protected by the firewall or a security group that does not have any rule in place to allow inboud traffic from your local IP adress.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if you configured a port for your container but maybe you have to see the Inbound and the Outbound ports rules of your VM network and add the right one.

See image below:
[image]